# Comparing two non-linear biological models: differences in y vs. differences in slope

Tags: modeling, model-comparison, ecology

I'm an ecology PhD student, but unfortunately not a very mathematically sophisticated one.  I am interested in ways to compare two non-linear models. I was really impressed with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723157/how-to-compare-two-curves-arrays-of-points), which covers part of my question, about looking at the absolute area between the curves. Thinking about it further, it seems to me that it might be more biologically meaningful to look at the slopes at points (x, y1) vs (x, y2) over the range of x values, since the slope is the indicator of the relationship between the predictor (lets say age) and the response (lets say body mass).

I'm imagining a comparison of two populations: one in which the gestation period was long, and one in which the gestation period was short. If the relationship between age and body mass are the same for these two groups, but contingent on the birth weight (longer gestation = more mass at birth) the curves could behave in exactly the same way, but be offset by that initial difference. The area between the curves could be large, while the slopes at each x value would be the identical.

I suppose that my questions are - does this make sense? If not, why not? If so, is there an obvious way to make this sort of comparison (between slopes)? Is there a way to make a comparison that takes into account both the difference in area between two curves **and** the difference in the behavior of the slopes? If I do tackle this, I will be using R.

Also, bearing in mind that I'm thinking of biologically realistic models, does this make sense? Slope at any value of x seems like it could be pretty independent of the slope at the adjacent values of x, whereas area, or more precisely the absolute difference in y-values, seems like it is only going to vary so much from the difference in y-values at adjacent values of x. Using the same hypothetical example, actual body weight is only going to change so much over the course of a day, but the rate of change in body weight could vary tremendously over the same time span.

Sorry for rambling, and I'm interested to hear what you think about this.

Comment: Starting by formulating a biologically meaningful measure of difference is a very good idea. The problem with "area between the curves" is that it is arbitrary and may be meaningless. "Arbitrary" follows from the fact that area between the curves (I presume *absolute* area is really meant) is just their $L^1$ distance, which is generalized by all the $L^p$ distances for any $1\le p\le \infty$.  Why should $p=1$ be privileged? (No reason at all...) What you may want to add to your considerations are thoughts about whether fits at different $x$ should have different *weights* in this comparison.

Comment: I did mean absolute area, I'll correct that, thanks. The idea of weighting fits at different x values is an interesting one. I think you mean based on a biological interpretation of x, for instance, one range of x may represent infancy, another old age, etc. If so, that makes sense to me. I also wonder if the sign of the slope should be taken into consideration seperately from differences in the magnitude. There may be a very different biological interpretation of the difference between slopes +1 and -1 and between slopes +1 and +3.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question. Do you want to compare a linear vs a non-linear model and see which describes better the relationship between age and body mass? If so, you could just build a regular linear model and another one say with a quadratic relationship and then calculate AICc for both and see which one is best. Is that what you want?